# Call MS graph without any pre-configurations

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to call MS graph search API (programmatically / C#) with MS accounts for authentication but without any pre-configurations in Azure AD or MS Identity server, is that available?

Comment: If you want to use a protected resource like Microsoft Graph then you need to create Azure AD application, set permission/scopes, get access token using that you can access Microsoft Graph. This is a pre-requisite.

Comment: Here's the doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Graph is a RESTful web API that enables you to access Microsoft Cloud service resources. After you register your app in Azure AD/Identity and get authentication tokens for a user or service, you can make requests to the Microsoft Graph API. Here's the [documentation for it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api).

Comment: Thanks for reply, but graph-explorer as an example (and I know we cannot compare) I don't have to register app or do anything in Azure AD so I thought I can do the same in code where I can login and use (username, password) then I can get the returned token to call graph api!

Comment: Yes Graph Explorer is an application registered in Azure AD. Thats why you can able to access the Microsoft Graph, by providing your tenant info, make the Graph API calls. Similarly you can do the same with POSTMAN too, but you need to register the app in Azure AD before you can POSTMAN :)

Comment: I moved the above to answer. Consider upvoting it; so it can be useful to others in the community. But if you have more questions, do ask - love to help.